# Javascript - Wondering if this Singleton can be used

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I have the following Singleton which I thought it was almost bulletproof. Except that I can write

```
  c1.instance = 8; 
  console.log(c1.instance);
```

Is the code below a wrong implementation of the Singleton Pattern?

```
      // <![CDATA[ 
        var Singleton = (function(){
           function Singleton()
           {
              this.username = 'foo1';
              this.password = 'foo2';
           }
           var instance;
           return {
             getInstance: function()
             {
                if(!instance)
                {
                   instance = new Singleton();
                   instance.constructor = null;
                }
                return instance;
             }
           };   
        })();
        var c1 = Singleton.getInstance();
        var c2 = Singleton.getInstance();
        console.assert(c1 === c2, 'The objects are not the same');
        // ]]>
```

Comment: The singleton looks good. I'm not sure if it is a good idea to compare objects that way.

Comment: I just tested your code, and the both objects were the same, I have done the same whenever I wanted to use Singleton pattern and I think this is actually one of the best solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c1 holds the instance if you type c1.instance=8 you are declaring a field named instance with value 8 in c1. Your implementation is correct.

Regards.

Comment: I think I understood. I was thinking that instance could be turned to a property after the object was created. But it's merely a variable ... many thanks.